# If a metal's solvent extraction process is exothermic, then the stripping is necessarily endothermic?

Tags: thermodynamics

I checked some articles, including [*Hydrometallurgy ***2012***, 133-144, 185-191*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304386X11002763) and [*Hydrometallurgy **2000**, 57, 269-275*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304386X00001092). In all research papers I checked, an exothermic stripping process followed an endothermic solvent extraction process and vise versa. First, what reasons can be behind such phenomena? Second, is such a claim necessarily right in all cases?